# Flex 4.6 - Air 3.2 - Why are the graphics drawn with an offset?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.6

[image: image with offset]

You can see in the image above that the display of the game is offsetted by some amount vertically. The white section is not supposed to be there. In fact the blue is meant to be flush with the bottom of the screen.

This happened by making three changes to a previously perfectly working project: change the SDK to the new 4.6 Flex release candidate including 3.2 air player with support for Stage3d. Another change is in the Air Application Descriptor file: changed the xmlns to end in number 3.2 instead of 2.6. Finally, in the compiler option, I added: "-swf-version:13" Nothing else has changed. In fact, if I revert to the 4.5.1 SDK, the graphics show as expected.

I have looked for a couple of hours for a solution, but I haven't found anything...

OS: mac
IDE: Flash Builder 4.6 trial
Device: the Flash Builder device simulator, but also seen on a real device
Application settings: fullscreen, landscape, renderMode=direct/gpu (same thing), size: 1024x600
Stage alignment: TOP_LEFT
Stage scaling: none
Project type: Mobile ActionScript

As I said, just the fact of changing to 4.6 introduced the problem and I can toggle it at will be reverting to 4.5.1, so the code hasn't changed. I can add that the white section in the graphic is actually a repeat of the last row of pixels (bleed basically) all the way to the bottom of the screen. With other graphics, that section changes - so not always white.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Why not showing any source code?

Answer (score 1):

I received a tip that setting the fullscreen app variable in the application descriptor file to 'false' instead of the normal 'true' for a game will solve the problem while you are developing on the desktop. It works.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when using gpu/direct renderMode and fullScreen in your app descriptor. I can confirm that setting fullScreen to false fixes the issue. You will need to set it back for mobile testing.